# Notification sometimes skips the first alert, always works on second fire

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I been working on an extension and I'm ready to release it.
I been learning a lot from all of your guyses experience and I'm ready to help if I can.

I need help with my notification pop up, currently it sometimes works,it always works on the second run.
  Anyone has dealt with this before?

```
chrome.notifications.create(
                      'success',{   
                      type: 'basic', 
                      iconUrl: 'coo.png', 
                      title: "coo", 
                      message: "sent to: " +title ,
                      silent:true,
                      priority:0 
                      },
                  function(){});
                  chrome.notifications.clear('success', function (){}) });
                     }
```

This is what I'm doing to create the notification, perhaps use update instead of create?

Thanks all :)

Comment: The API is asynchronous so create() and clear() have a race, each time a random one runs first. I don't see any need for clear() here, just remove it.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hey thank you for the help, I constantly see you helping the community in that is really awesome of you.    The reason why I clear it, it's because I want the user to see the notification every time the function is ran instead of just hiding in the task bar. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, then call them in succession: chrome.notifications.clear('success', () => { chrome.notifications.create(.........) })

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your help, it's still not working 100% for some reason if a notification is up and I fire it again it will replace the notification which would be the perfect scenario but now it's a little better with your help.Now it always displays the first time but not the second, it will display on the third lol. I'll keep tinkering around with it if I find a solution I'll post it.

Comment: Maybe you need an intermediate timeout e.g. clear('...', () => setTimeout(() => create(....), 100))

Comment: @wOxxOm That worked! adding the timeout worked thanks!